# How do i stop concatenation between two state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, concatenation, jsx

Every time i try to run this block of code it just concatenates a and b together. All other math operators work as expected except for +. Is there any way to stop/work around this?

```
export default class DataInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: 0,
      b: 0,
    };
  }


  handleCalculate = () => {
    const { a, b} = this.state;
    let average = (a + b)/2;

    this.setState({ results: average });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.DataInput}>
          <View style={styles.value}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Bench Press"
              onChangeText={a => this.setState({ a })}
              keyboardType={"numeric"}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.value}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Shoulder Press"
              onChangeText={b => this.setState({ b })}
              keyboardType={"numeric"}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: _"it just concatenates a and b together"_ - Then either `a` or `b` (or both) is a string

Comment: @Andreas if i set their initial values within state to Number or null i get the same effect

Comment: @Nit i tried that also using parseInt() still didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: `let average = (parseInt(a)+parseInt(b))/2`

Answer (score 0):

while updating the state on input, it should be

```
onChangeText={a => this.setState({...this.state, a })} //bench press
onChangeText={a => this.setState({...this.state, b })} //shoulder press
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to destructure a & b for your operation see code below:

```
  export default class DataInput extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          a: 0,
          b: 0,
        };
      }


      handleCalculate = () => {
        const { a, b} = this.state; // destructure a & b 
        let average = (a + b)/2;

        this.setState({ results: average });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.DataInput}>
              <View style={styles.value}>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Bench Press"
                  onChangeText={value => this.setState({ a: value })}
                  keyboardType={"numeric"}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.value}>
                <TextInput
                  placeholder="Shoulder Press"
                  onChangeText={value => this.setState({ b: value })}
                  keyboardType={"numeric"}
                />
              </View>
          </View>
```

Comment: the {b, s } =this.state was a type on my part sorry. fixed it